# ASP.NET C#, dynamic drop down in repeater causing full post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, repeater, autopostback

I have a page that contains a Repeater, which contains server control elements, within an UpdatePanel and while all other controls behave normally, the Drop Down control causes a full postback every time.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:SomeWorkingControl ID="swc" runat="server" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="0" Value="0" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is vaugely what my code looks like, the DropDownList control is actually in a UserControl, but the theory is the same.

If I apply an event to SomeWorkingControl then there is an Ajax postback and all is fine.

However, the event associated with the DropDownList causes a full postback! I know usually you would set an Async trigger for the DropDown, but since it is created in a repeater (and therefore I can not know how many there will be) so I don't really see how that could work.

Is there anybody who has experienced this before and knows a workaround perhaps?

Comment: do you have triggers in your UpdatePanel ? can you update full aspx code with update panel

Comment: No, there are no triggers in the UpdatePanel at the moment. That would usually be what I'd do, but since the DropDownList in inside a Repeater, I'm not sure what to point the trigger at.

I can't really post the full ASPX, it's a large page with the UpdatePanel in the ASPX and the offending code in a User Control, inside a repeater and then another User Control.

The UpdatePanel is basic and looks like this.

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="SearchResultUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            ...ascx -> repeater -> ascx 
        </ContentTemplate>
    </UpdatePanel>

Comment: You may want to simplify your layout--a `Repeater` is already designed to repeat markup for each row.  Encapsulating that markup in a `UserControl` is only helpful if you plan on using that markup elsewhere.

Comment: That's exactly why it is a User Control. It's a large scale project and the purpose of the DDL in question is for list paging and is used all over the place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
```

for:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="AutoID">
```

Recently I had the same problem and I found out that the ClientIDMode can solve it.

Please have a look here: [asp.net ClientIDMode Changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770142)

Comment: Excellent! That's done the trick and the postback in the update panel and it doesn't update the whole page with ClientIDMode="AutoID" in the DropDownList.

Thank you so much!

Comment: This is an old answer but just saved my bacon, it looks like repeaters don't handle ID's well for DDLs then!!!
Thanks for sharing :)